# Getting values back from two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out a query where it will list every row in a specific column the associated data  in another column:

[image]

So I want every value in the name column and a column next to it from another table. The value 44 below is a primary key, so if there is a value in that column I want to get the name of a column from another table who's primary key it belongs. If it is void I want nothing or void to be returned.

If I do:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme], [ThemeType] 
WHERE [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
```

it is only returning the values where both exist. How can I get both back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this you'll need a LEFT JOIN AKA `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
Left Outer Join [ThemeType] on [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
```

You can understand how joins work, and how you would show different results with the following image.

[image]

Image Credit to [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)